# ZIP Embedding throws error

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, embedding, flash-builder

I want to embed a ZIP-file into my AS3/Air-application (with Flash Builder) and open it via FZip. For embedding, I use this code:

```
[Embed(source='../bin/art/resources.zip', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static const rsClass:Class;
```

When I try to save the project the program chrashes and throws an error:

"Workspace is being build" has encountered a problem. During "Workspace is being build" an internal error has occured. (this is just a bad translation, not original) Java heap space

I click OK, the internal error appears:

The error "Disc space too low" has appeared. Look into the Readme-File at "Run Eclipse" you will find information [...] It is recommended to end the workbench. Do you want to end the workbench? yes/no

In an earlier version of this post I said, that the program doesnt start. That is not true. Only saving causes this error. Because of the saving errors, an earlier version of the program is started, but without errors. When I try to make a bytearray out of the zip, it causes an error (initial content not found), but I suppose the zip doesnt load, so this is not unusual.

Comment: That happens ONLY when I try to embed a zip. If I use the same code for embedding an xml, nothing unusual happens. I thought, maybe it could depend on how the zip is compressed, so I tried out several zip-programs to produce uncompressed files, but no difference. Can somebody at least tell me, if it is possible that the problem is the zip file? Because the error message appears, even when I try to just save my code. Is it possible that Flash Builder checks the embedded files while saving?

Comment: Have you tried to load the zip instead of embedding? maybe your zip is gigantic:)?

Comment: No it is not, but it is going to be. I want to embed it, because I think it is the only way to pack all of my game graphics into the AIR installer. If I just load the zip, I have to manually add it to the program folder. Please correct me, if theres a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should NOT embed this ZIP but load it instead, you can add to the AIR package any files/folders.

To do it:

- in Flash IDE go to "AIR for Android Settings" or "AIR for iOS Settings" and at the bottom of the dialogue box you have "Included files:" field then add folder or file you need,
- for FlashDevelop what ever will be in *bin* folder will be packaged in air as described [here](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7774)
- In Flex it will be the *src* folder and in the export wizzard you can select which files to include like described [here](http://www.charlesclements.net/blog/?p=154).

**Edit** also you should consider for very large files following idea:

don't include big files (or just basic elements) and download big files and save on user device e.g. on sdcard, and then load it from there.

best regards

Comment: Thx for your reply. But I just found out that it doesnt matter. On windows the installation will crash if the air file is bigger than 500mb or something. Therefore I will have to find another way. Maybe I will find out how to make a custom exe installer and let it copy all files to the program directory. In this case I dont have to zip them.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct, because I would have done it this way. The only thing to mention would be that in FlashBuilder the files you want to include have to be in the src folder, for whatever reason.